# While testing error responses, the test fails with the expected error (React/Jest/ReactQuery/Axios/MSW)

Tags: axios, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query, msw

I am trying to test error states of the following MSW rest endpoint:

```
import { rest } from 'msw'

export const exceptionHandlers = [
  rest.post(config.accountApiUrl + '/login', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.status(500),
      ctx.json({ data: { message: 'Mock Error Message' } })
    )
  })
]
```

This endpoint is called in a custom hook return function thats using React Query's mutateAsync:

```
  const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(AuthApi.login)

  const handleLogin = async (props): Promise<void> => {
    await mutateAsync(props, {
      onSuccess: async () => {
        // this block tests fine
      }
      onError: async () => {
        console.log('!!!')
        // it reaches this block, '!!!' is logged to the console,
        // but the test still fails with `Request failed with status code 500`
      }
    })
  }

   return handleLogin
```

In a test file:

```
  it('handles network errors', async () => {
    mswServer.use(...exceptionHandlers)
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const screen = render(<LoginForm />)
    const submitButton = screen.getByTestId('Login.Submit')
    // Complete form
    await user.click(submitButton)
  })
```

It doesnt matter what comes after that, the test always fails with

```
Request failed with status code 500

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
      at XMLHttpRequestOverride.onloadend (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:54:7)
      at XMLHttpRequestOverride.trigger (node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/interceptors/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequestOverride.ts:176:17)
      at node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/src/interceptors/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequestOverride.ts:354:16
```

But its supposed to fail with status 500. That's the whole point. If I change the handler to return another error, ie `ctx.status(404)`, then the test just fails with that error code.

I've tried [wrapping the assertion in a try/catch block](https://blog.bitsrc.io/successfully-throwing-async-errors-with-the-jest-testing-library-fda17261733a) but the same thing results. I see [examples online](https://youtu.be/dReoPIwDccY?t=693) of people doing (apparently) exactly this and it works fine, so I'm quite confused what's causing this. All other tests that check success states work as expected.

Comment: Test fails with 500 as you expected. And it does with 404 if you setup so. Whats the problem here again?

Comment: The problem is that it fails the test

Comment: are you sure that the test is failing? If so, which error is the test failing with? All I see is that the request error gets logged, which doesn't automatically imply that the test failed. Also, I don't see your test asserting anything? You're getting the login button and then you click it. So what exactly is failing?

Comment: @TkDodo the test is definitely failing, and the only message is `Request failed with status code 500` or whatever code it's supposed to return from MSW. That's all the info I got. Whatever comes after the action that causes the mutation to run in the test is irrelevant, the test always fails before it gets to it. I tried to set up a sandbox/blitz to share but was too complicated

Comment: @TkDodo I've since noticed that this only happens with `mutateAsync` where the `onSuccess` and `onError` blocks are used like in the code in my question, if the hook is refactored to use `try/catch` like you show [in the docs](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#promises), the test passes. So maybe you can help settle a discussion between me and a coworker... if everything else stays the same, is there any benefit/hinderance/difference at all to refactoring all our mutations to use try/catch instead of the onError/onSuccess blocks? Thanks

Comment: I would use `mutate` with callbacks because it catches errors internally. With mutateAsync, you have to catch them for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same problem.

As far as i could understand, the problem is that in test environment there is no handler for the rejected promise.

https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/4109